# Disable Individual Plugins (specifically in Custom Post Types) on a per-post basis?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-development

The title pretty much says what I'm trying to accomplish, but more specifically I have a plugin that I made and it creates a custom post type, lets call them `newpages`. On these pages I have used `template_redirect` to take over the design of the pages, but some plugins appear, but I don't want to remove all of the plugins from loading, just a couple.

So I was wondering if it's possible to use something like custom fields to disable certain plugins on a per-post basis. Can anybody point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: It really depends on what are the plugins?

Comment: That's the thing, it will vary. I want to somehow make an array with all of the plugins that are currently activated and to be able to deactivate some of them per-post. I'll be deactivating them by adding a section in my meta box on the post editor that will add/change custom fields to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why not.

1. Hook to `template_redirect` (you already did).
2. Conditionals should work at this point, so use `is_single()` / `is_singular()` / etc to check for what you need.
3. Use `remove_action()`/`remove_filter()` to unhook unwanted functionality.

Comment: thanks for that, it clears up some things but I'm a bit confused as to how I would go about applying it. There are many plugins installed, I basically want to add a section in my meta box for the post editor where I can select/deselect specific plugins to activate/deactivate them for that specific post. Is this what you are describing above? In other words, I would probably need an array with all the plugin names to toggle them per post with a meta box and custom fields.

Comment: @Jared this is essentially describing more mild way to do it - you need to know what plugins are doing and what functionality they are hooking for that. Really not loading plugin conditionally would be **much** more complex.

Answer (score 1):

I was interested in accomplishing something like this before. There is a plugin named Plugin Organizer that I came across. It allows you to change the order that plugins are loaded and selectively disable them on a post types or page url basis. You can find it in the WordPress plugin directory.